# How to troubleshoot overheating and high battery drain in an Android Device?

Tags: battery, troubleshooting, overheating

#### **Device info**:

- Model  : Micromax Canvas Nitro A310
- Android Version : 4.4.2
- Kernel Version  : 3.4.67
- Device Status : Rooted, Philz touch recovery, Xposed Framework installed

#### **Issue**:

My(relative's) device is getting overheated (avg temperature ~ **48 deg** Celsius, max reached ~ **65 deg** Celsius) and the battery drains (**100% to ~9% in less than 7 hours** with usage of attending few calls only) very quickly even when its idle.

---

#### **About Overheating** :

I used [CPU Temperature](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yanyan.cputemp&hl=en) for profiling the apps with respect to temperature. Based on that, I auto-hibernated those apps in [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify.pro&hl=en)(**all experimental features enabled** except Telephony Wakeup, **working in Boost Mode**).

1. One main culprit I noticed is the [Runkeeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro&hl=en) app which requires **high-accuracy** (more battery consumption) location mode for smooth working. If I put this app in Greenify then it can't possibly be used **(will get hibernated)** for its intended purpose if the device screen turns off or goes to sleep.
2. Other culprit noticed was **Google Play Services** and **Gmail** (both updated to latest version) which I don't have any option to hibernate the former in Greenify and I'm not supposed to disable the former because of Runkeeper's demand for Maps and location.

---

#### **About Battery Drain**:

Battery usage from Settings didn't reveal anything useful at all. At the time of writing this question, I've put to test three apps:

- [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats&hl=en) and [Battery Stats Plus](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.rootuninstaller.bstats) **for profiling battery usage**;
- [DS Battery Saver](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.rootuninstaller.batrsaver)(free) **for keeping the drain low**.

This profiling will take at least 1-2 days and I'm not having high hopes from DS Battery Saver. Another point, my relative keeps GPS Off when not using Runkeeper. Usage of Runkeeper is for around 1-1.5 hour roughly in the morning.

---

#### **About Device**:

The device is only six months old with **2500mAh** battery. The surrounding environment temperature isn't much more than *34 deg* Celsius to corroborate any additional heating. Furthermore, no new apps were installed before when these issues came into my relative's attention. I take it as some new update in Google Services or other app could be a reason for this. But that is just a wild guess.

---

#### **Question**:

I need to know how should I proceed to troubleshoot both of these issues effectively? Is there a guide here or elsewhere for such, to do this in a sound manner rather than being haphazard? I aim to pinpoint the culprits here.

#### **Note**:

Although I have already made Nandroid and ADB backup, I don't want to reset my device. That is left if all else fails.

Comment: Also try Wae lock detector.

Comment: It is tricky to troubleshoot some problems. Sounds like similar problem that I had, battery drain started happening for my huawei p9 a few days ago all of a sudden, no apparent cause. Google Play Services top battery user but also a variety of other apps. In the end a suggestion to turn off automatic app updates solved the problem for me (after I had done general cleanup and os upgrade which had not solved problem). I guess problem was with one specific app doing something bad but would be impossible to troubleshoot root cause without extreme debug investigation!

Answer (score 1):

BBS is more confusing than GSAM battery companion. It provides more detail, but GSAM + root can tell you a lot. If you could provide screenshots of full charge, to fully dead we can point you in right direction; if this happens in 7 hours with the screen off and no interaction all the better it should be very trivial to find.

From there, you could use Xposed App Opps module to disable apps with excessive spyware.

I don't really help people (relatives, friends) with this stuff unless they're willing to understand 'why' themselves, easier to just recommend iPhone.

There's almost certainly a rogue app running around doing something. A picture would be worth a thousand words

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try GSAM. Are you asking for a picture of `battery statistics from Settings` upon 100% and 9%, or, running processes, or am I missing something here?

Comment: 9%. When you poke around in GSAM at lower battery I think you'll find it mostly self explanatory

Comment: @Firelord any luck?

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferred to restart the device, but before you do that, try clearing the ram and recent applications ALL THE TIME. If this fails, try battery doctor. It is a very useful tool that closes background apps and things you are not using.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to answer but I take it as you have missed my point overall. My device isn't short in RAM. And I've restarted it like 20 times since I installed xposed modules for profiling battery. But anyway, I'll do check what `battery doctor` can do for me.

Comment: My point was that programs could be running in the background. Battery doctor helps with that.